# array missing first record

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, zip

Following script fetches images files from my database and creates a zip file. For some reason it misses the first file of the query, the print_r is there to show me what it is zipping and on every occasion [0]=>myfile.jpg is actually the second file not the first.

anyone know why?

```
//create an empty array
$file_names = array();
//fetch the names from database
while ($row_rsParentGal = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsParentGal))
{
//Add the values to the array
  $file_names[] = $row_rsParentGal['filename'];
}

print_r ($file_names);

// instantate object
$zip = new ZipArchive();

// create and open the archive 
if ($zip->open("$zipfilename", ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
die ("Could not open archive");
}

// add each file in the file list to the archive
foreach($file_names as $files)
{
    $zip->addFile($sourcefolder.$files, $files);
    // uncomment to show list of files added to archive on results page
    echo $sourcefolder.$files."<br />";
}

$zip->close();
```

Comment: so what's your problem?

Comment: please paste only required code to show.

Comment: So the problem is with your query if $file_names doesn't have the right values, yes? Also, you shouldn't use the mysql_* functions.

Comment: Im not sure, all I know is the rsulting array is always missing the actual first record of the MySQL lookup.